# could not install google play services: download interrupted

Tags: android

I am trying to install google play services. In android SDK manager log I am getting the following error message:

```
Done loading packages.
Preparing to install archives 
Downloading Google Play services, revision 13
Download interrupted: Unknown Host dl-ssl.google.com
Downloading Google USB Driver, revision 8
Download interrupted: Unknown Host dl-ssl.google.com
Done. Nothing was installed.
```

Can anybody tell me why this is happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

pen your sdk as administrator , It will work..

Comment: could you please elaborate?

Comment: open your android sdk file by clicking run as administrator for first time..(right click->run as adminstrator)